# Flutter: Class '_Map<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'call'

Tags: flutter, dart

Why is this error comming?

Class '_Map<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'call'.

```
  Future<AttendanceModel?> getTodayAttendance() async {
    final List result = await supabase
        .from(Constants.attendanceTable)
        .select()
        .eq('employee_id', supabase.auth.currentUser!.id)
        .eq('date', todayDate);
    
    if (result.isNotEmpty) {
      attendanceModel = AttendanceModel.fromJson(result.single());
    }

    return attendanceModel;
  }
```

**Inside Model Class**

```
  factory AttendanceModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    return AttendanceModel(
      id: data['employee_id'],
      date: data['date'],
      checkIn: data['check_in'],
      checkOut: data['check_out'],
      createdAt: DateTime.parse(data['created_at']),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Do you know the line where the error occurs?

Comment: Isn't `single()` async? Maybe you have to add `single()` at the end of the `await supabase...` part. Also consider `return Future.value(attendanceModel);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`single` is a getter and not a function. By putting `()` behind it you are trying to call whatever `single` returns, which is a `Map` in this case, which can't be called. So simply remove the `()` like

```
  attendanceModel = AttendanceModel.fromJson(result.single);
```